# Is it possible to use Traefik in a Docker swarm and still use container-label-based routing?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, traefik

As it is mentioned in the title, I am looking for a way to use Traefik in a Docker Swarm cluster. However, different subdomains should point to different containers. But these are all distributed "identically" through a stack on all nodes. I would then enable routing via manual added labels at the container level. However, as far as I have noticed, in swarm mode Traefik only supports routing by labels at service level? Can I do this in a swarm mode also on container level?

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Docker, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, but networking-related, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score -1):

Default Traefik behaviour using inside docker swarm deployments is the normal RR mechanism Traeik offers to hit containers. You have to enable the RR to the VIP Service IPs that Swarm provides if you want Traefik to work with services instead of containers. This behaviour is configured using Traefik's [lbswarm](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/providers/docker/#traefikdockerlbswarm) property.